# Transaction Count Discrepancy Between Ecommerce Overview and Sales Performance

Tags: google-analytics

Hopefully someone is able to shed some insight here as I'm running out of ideas.  When I look at a single day's transaction count in the Ecommerce Overview section vs. the Sales Performance section, I am seeing different numbers.

Initially, I wanted to chalk it up to sampled data but both reports claim to be based on 100% of sessions.  The thing I find odd is that the shield next to the report name is green (unsampled) for the Ecommerce Overview and it is yellow (sampled) for the Sales Performance.

Perhaps it is a bug in GA where the shield is yellow but claims to be based on 100% of sessions?  I've attached screenshots of the two reports below.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for any insight offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to duplicate transactions (2 transaction being sent with same ID).

One way to check for that is creating custom report with ‘transactions id‘ as a dimension and transactions as a metric and then sort by transactions metric.